# how to configure a Keycloak server instance to support both development and UAT environments?

Tags: keycloak, settings, development-environment, production-environment

should we define **two different Realms**? one for UAT and one for development? or should we define **a separate set of Clients for UAT and another set for development**? because obviously the URLs are different. or is there a magic way to segregate development/UAT settings in **one client**?
appreciate your ideas.
the problem is for example when we define root URL, which for development is something like http://localhost:3000 but of course for UAT must be another URL. I am looking for some best practice here.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you need 2 independent Keycloak server instances (not independent realms or clients). That will allow you to test new Keycloak versions in dev env without breaking prod env.

Of course you may accept risk (because cost, complexity, ...) and use only independent realms/clients.

Comment: In this case, how can we ensure (1) consistent configurations between dev/prod/other environments, while also (2) allowing for continuous development where those configurations may change over time? Should we simply write scripts to define the environment via requests to the admin API?